# unsupported major.minor version 51.0 on Jar built by Warbler

Tags: ruby, jruby, warbler

Last night for a separate project I installed the latest Java SDK.

Now, the jar I build using Warbler says it is using the wrong version.  I have built this jar many times before and not had this issue.  I am building the jar on my local machine using OSX and then running it on a Windows box (Windows Server 2008).

I have a feeling that before I added the latest java SDK it just used the default one on my Mac.

I am trying to figure out how my java SDK version affects warbler.  I didn't think it would but that is the only variable that has changed.

Any ideas?  Places to start, etc. would be nice.

Comment: It means you're trying to *run* the app on a lower JRE.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I cannot upgrade the JRE on the remote box (Windows Server 2008).  I need to build my jar to use that JRE.

Just not sure how to do that with warbler.

Comment: You might just be able to set a JAVA_HOME, but I'm not sure. It's not clear to me how to set the compiler level.